# Best way to keep a very large amount of images in RAM in C++

Tags: c++, vector, ram, deque

I would like my program to keep a large amount of pictures in RAM memory for very fast access. For a complicated computation, I would like to push my system to the limit and let my program use potentially *all* available RAM. (Whatever this amount may be).

What would be the best way to do this? My pictures are stored in simple 2d RGBA arrays. I thought first of using a `std::vector`, but I have the impression that internally vectors are stored in a contiguous way. Since the vector would be huge, perhaps this would lead to problems?

I wonder if `std::deque` would be better to do this sort of thing? Since, for `std::deque` the data is (as far as I understand, pls point it out if I am wrong) *not* stored in a contiguous way.

Any other related tips would be welcome.
I only need to load the pictures once.

Comment: At the end of the day, your access patterns determine data layout. If you will be walking the image from left to right, sequential storage is fine. If you intend to process NxN blocks, consider [swizzling](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/texture-tiling-and-swizzling/) such that each block is stored sequentially.

Comment: As for the choice of data structures: forget about `std::deque`. You *want* sequential access. `std::vector` can handle large sizes just fine. Make sure to `.reserve()` the right amount of memory so you don't needlessly resize as you read bytes.

Comment: That _vectors are stored in a contiguous way_ is good for you as it improves cache locality and hence performance (as long as data is processed contiguous as well). If you are afraid that memory fragmentation could be an issue (to allocate that contiguous memory), I don't think so. The contiguous storage is in terms of virtual addresses. The OS might spread this to distinct physical addresses using the internal paging. As long as you don't exhaust the complete physical memory I wouldn't concern too much about this. (That's for modern PCs. Embedded H/W could be another topic...)

Comment: If, as you say, your calculations are complicated, you might find they dwarf the time to load your images from a fast SSD anyway and if that's the case, there would be no advantage to holding them in RAM. You can also hold compressed JPEG images in RAM, by the way and decode on demand.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comments, they are very helpful. At Botje: If I understand you correctly, so say I should first do .reserve(1000) on my std::vector<Image> to allocate all the needed memory (say, when loading 1000 pictures). Problem is that I do not know the sizes of the images - but I can do an estimate (and I do not care if I overestimate a little bit).

Comment: You didn't provide enough context. Depending on what kind operation you need perform on those pictures there are different solutions. Also information about data type (number of images, size of images) has impact on possible solution. Curtly this question is to wide, you can write a book or two.

Comment: Ok I get it now. If the image size is variable, the Image class would probably only contain a pointer to the actual RGBA data. So the .reserve(1000) only reserves space for 1000 pointers to images as opposed to 1000-images. At Mark: Thanks for your comment, I thought about it, but I am a bit skeptical in my case, because I need a lot of accesses to the images the speed of the computation will probably be bounded by those memory accesses, not the actual arithmetic (sorry, of course the word "complicated" does not explain this).

Comment: If you just need to load the images once and read them many times, the simplest c/c++ pointer(maybe char * or int *) is enough, stl or other complicated thing isn't needed. But you need to allocate a huge continuous physical memory from kernel first, it's not difficult if you are using linux, you may need to alter kernel parameter to allocate huge continuouse physical memory; but I don't know how to

Comment: allocate such memory on windows, I think it should be similar on windows. And then you can map the allocated physical memory to a pointer, and then you just need to copy data into the huge memory, and then access it with a simple pointer. You may also pay attention to cache programming such as access memory row by row rather than column by column, it will improve the locality cache performance.